# update a select box without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is it possible to add a new option dynamically to a select box and also can be added to the database using Ajax. i am looking for a button which appends new option to the select box as well as to add that field to the database. Thanks...

### EDIT 2

is it possible to update the select box values without page refresh, The case is when i adds new data to database and not making use of .append here...

Comment: You can add new option like this `$('select').append('<option value="0">--Select--</option>');`

Comment: thats clear thanks @ Manoj Kumawat  ...but meantime i want that to be added th the database also, is it possible

Comment: Yes after append you can call an ajax and save data to database

Answer (score 2):

Try this

This is for add new `option` in `select`

```
$('select').append('<option value="0">--Select--</option>');
```

And after adding new option you can call ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'url',
    data:'data',
    type:'post',
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

In server side put code to save data in database.

**Edit**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'url',
    data:'data',
    type:'post',
    success:function(data){
    //data will be list of values which you want in options and this sent from server side in json result
    $(data).each(function(index,item){
        $('select').append('<option value="'+item.val+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Manoj Kumawat : can u look at the EDIT 2 section please

Comment: You want add value to database and than reload `select` `options` without page refresh ? @SyamiliV

Comment: Yes you should send list of values in success function @SyamiliV

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4yh3Lor/1/

HTML

```
<button id="pop-btn">Populate</button>
<select id="options-box">
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pop-btn").on("click",function(){
        value = "2";
        name = "Option 2";
        $("#options-box").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+name+"</option>");
        $.ajax({
            url: "addtodb.php?value="+value+"&name="+name,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP - While this is valid, make you sure sanitize your inputs into the query to avoid SQL Injection.

```
$value = $_GET["value"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (name,value) VALUES ('$name','$value')");
```

Comment: thats clear thanks @FirstLegion ...but meantime i want that to be added to the database also, is it possible

Comment: hey you should have made me do all that... thanks for giving me the Big Picture !!

Comment: All good! But do make sure you sanitize your inputs into the database. It is very important. You can read more here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php

Comment: hey, all done as above.. in my other Page i have a issue..the process is just the reverse, **1** adds to the database **2**  but only after reloading does the updation of my select box occurs.- i would like to update the select box data updated dynamically without page refresh... @FirstLegion can u guide me

Comment: @SyamiliV - I can help you if you provide more information. It's a little confusing as to what you are asking. But no worries, post up a new stack overflow question and link me here and I will take a look at it.